# Git-commit unable to open vim

Tags: git, bash, vim, commit, git-commit

Recently I installed `bash-it` into my terminal. Now, when I try to execute `git commit` the terminal shows me this error:

`/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: cannot run /usr/bin/mate -w: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.`

Before `bash-it`, the commit command correctly opened vim.
Of course I've tried to change the `core.editor` in git to "vim" but it does not work anyway.

Could you please help me to solve this? I really like vim, it was super easy and fast...I don't want to use TextMate to edit the commit message.

PS: I'm using Mac OSX

Comment: Check your `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables. One of them probably points to `/usr/bin/mate`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you were right, i had to enviroment variables that pointer to:
```# Set my editor and git editor
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/mate"
export GIT_EDITOR='/usr/bin/mate -v'```
I edited my .bash_profile and deleted those to, set vim:
```# Set my editor and git editor
export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
export GIT_EDITOR='/usr/bin/vim'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was that i had two environment variables that pointed to `/usr/bin/mate` in my `.bash_profile`
so i edit them to point to `vim`

Answer (score 52):

Try using the below command. Should be able to set your editor back to vi or vim. However, you might have to give the absolute path to vim.

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Comment: As i said, my core.editor was already set to vim, the problem was that i had to enviroment vars that pointed to `/usr/bin/mate` in my  `.bash_profile`

Comment: For me this fixed the issue of when I tried to rebase a text file would be opened in my editor, I needed to use vim for renaming the commit messages and traverse the most recent few commits

Answer (score 10):

As "abalos" answered,

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

If you do not want to use **`vim`** or you do not have **`vim`** installed in some case,
You can also use **`nano`** editor

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```

Comment: I have set `git config --global core.editor subl` but still getting errors.
```
git commit
fatal: cannot run subl: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'subl'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Answer (score 9):

If other answers don't work, try `export GIT_EDITOR=vim`

Comment: I have used it recently; and it works pretty well!